# React-Native doesn't extract strings from associative array in map

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, arrays, react-native

I cannot put strings from the associative array to another associative array. This is very weird phenomenon. This is the code and result

[Code]

```
    p.phone_score_list.map(par => {
      console.log(`par`, par);
      console.log(typeof par.ipa);

      phoneScoreList.push({
        ipa: par.ipa,
        // ipa: par.phone,
        phone: par.phone,
        pronuncedIpa: par.pronuncedIpa,
        qualityScore: par.quality_score,
        soundMostLike: par.sound_most_like,
      });
    });
    console.log(`phoneScoreList`, phoneScoreList)
```

The result is below.
"ipa" and "pronuncedIpa" are "n" in the par parameter but after inputting the ipa into another associative array like the above code, it's gonna be undefined. Do you know the reason and how to handle it?

[image]

This is phone_score_list.

[image]

Comment: can you also paste p.phone_score_list value

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're assigning references to an object that has since been dropped from memory. I would try to create a new object like so

```
const newObject = { ...par };
phoneScoreList.push(newObject);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work well